# Wordpress The_content() returns null home

Tags: php, wordpress

i have the content function at the end of this code that must show something under the posts and it shows in the single page (post details page)
but in the home just shows nothing at all
here is my code

```
    <?php
/**
 * The template for content.
 *
 * @package Webdoone
 * @subpackage Ruby
 * @since Ruby 1.1
 */

?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('wow fadeInUp'); ?>>

        <?php if (has_post_format('gallery')) { ?>

            <?php $images = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_format_gallery_images', true); ?>

            <?php
            if ($images) { ?>
                <div class="post-img">
                    <div class="post-type-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
                    </div>
<div class="outter"><div class="inner">  
                    <ul class="bxslider">
                    <?php
                    foreach ($images as $image) {
                        if ((get_theme_mod('ruby_webdoone_home_layout_settings') === 'home-ful' ) || (get_theme_mod('ruby_webdoone_archive_layout_settings') === 'arch-ful' ) || (get_theme_mod('ruby_webdoone_post_layout_settings') === 'post-ful' )) {
                            $the_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image, 'ruby_webdoone_custom_width');
                            $the_caption = get_post_field('post_excerpt', $image); ?>
                            <li><img src="<?php echo esc_url($the_image[0]); ?>"
                            <?php
                            if ($the_caption) {?>
                                title="<?php echo esc_attr($the_caption); ?>"<?php
                            }; ?> /></li><?php
                        } else {
                            $the_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image, 'ruby_webdoone_full_width');
                            $the_caption = get_post_field('post_excerpt', $image); ?>
                            <li><img src="<?php echo esc_url($the_image[0]); ?>"
                            <?php
                            if ($the_caption) { ?>
                                title="<?php echo esc_attr($the_caption); ?>"<?php
                            }; ?> /></li><?php
                        };
                    }; ?>
                    </ul>
</div></div>
                </div><?php
            }
            } elseif (has_post_format('video')) { ?>
                                <div class="post-img video">
                                    <div class="post-type-icon">
                                        <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>
                                    </div>
<div class="outter"><div class="inner">  
                                    <div class="fluid-width-video-wrapper" >
                                    <?php $ruby_video = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_format_video_embed', true); ?>
                                    <?php

                                        echo $ruby_video;

                                    ?>
                                    </div></div></div>
                                </div><?php
            } elseif (has_post_format('audio')) { ?>

                                <div class="post-img audio">
                                    <div class="post-type-icon">
                                        <i class="fa fa-music"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php $ruby_audio = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_format_audio_embed', true); ?>
                                    <?php
                                    if (wp_oembed_get($ruby_audio)) {
                                        echo wp_oembed_get($ruby_audio);
                                    } else {
                                        echo esc_url($ruby_audio);
                                    }; ?>
                                </div><?php
            } else {
                if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                                        <div class="post-img">
                                        <?php if (is_sticky()) { ?>
                                            <div class="post-type-icon">
                                                <i class="fa fa-thumb-tack"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php } else { ?>
                                            <div class="post-type-icon">
                                                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php }

            if (is_home()) {
                if (!empty($_GET['layout'])) {
                    $layout = $_GET['layout'];
                } else {
                    $layout = '';
                };
                if ((get_theme_mod('ruby_webdoone_home_layout_settings') === 'home-ful') || ($layout === 'home-ful')) { ?>
<div class="outter"><div class="inner">  

                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><div class="grid home-full-thumb"><figure class="effect-jazz"><?php the_post_thumbnail('ruby_webdoone_full_width'); ?><figcaption></figcaption></figure></div></a> </div></div><?php
                } else { ?>
<div class="outter"><div class="inner"> 
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>"><div class="grid home-post-thumb"><figure class="effect-jazz"><?php the_post_thumbnail('ruby_webdoone_content_width'); ?><figcaption></figcaption></figure></div></a>
</div></div>
<?php
                };
            } elseif (is_single()) {
                if (!empty($_GET['layout'])) {
                    $layout = $_GET['layout'];
                } else {
                    $layout = '';
                };
                if ((get_theme_mod('ruby_webdoone_post_layout_settings') === 'post-ful') || ($layout === 'post-ful')) {
                    ?>
            <div class="outter"><div class="inner">    
                <?php   the_post_thumbnail('ruby_webdoone_full_width'); ?>

</div></div>
                <?php
                } else {

                ?>
   <div class="outter"><div class="inner">    
                <?php    the_post_thumbnail('ruby_webdoone_content_width');?>
</div></div>
<?php
                };
            } else {
                if (!empty($_GET['layout'])) {
                    $layout = $_GET['layout'];
                } else {
                    $layout = '';
                };
                if ((get_theme_mod('ruby_webdoone_archive_layout_settings') === 'arch-ful') || ($layout === 'arch-ful')) { ?>
<div class="outter"><div class="inner">  
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('ruby_webdoone_full_width'); ?></a>
</div></div>
<?php
                } else { ?>
<div class="outter"><div class="inner">  

                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('ruby_webdoone_content_width'); ?></a>
</div></div>

<?php
                };
            };?>
                    </div><?php
        };
    }; ?>

    <div class="post-header">
        <?php
        if (is_home()) { ?>
            <h3><a class="pos-header-title-link" href="<?php esc_url(the_permalink()); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3><?php
        } elseif (is_single()) { ?>
            <h1 class="pos-header-title-link"><?php the_title(); ?></h1><?php
        } else { ?>
            <h2><a class="pos-header-title-link" href="<?php esc_url(the_permalink()); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2><?php
        } ?>

        <div class="post-info">
            <span class="author"><?php esc_html_e('Author:', 'ruby') ?> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> \ </span>
            <span class="date"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?> \ </span><span class="cat"><?php the_category(', '); ?></span>
            <span class="comments-count">\ <?php printf( _nx( '1 Comment', '%1$s Comments', get_comments_number(), 'comments number', 'ruby' ), number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ) ); ?></span>
    </div>


    </div>
    <div class="post-data" itemprop="articleBody"><?php

the_content(); 



  ?> </div>

</article>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

[image: actually content must show this pictures section under posts and text or etc have no problem]
how can i fix this ? 
actually content must show this pictures section under posts and text or etc have no problem when i remove this func , wordpress wont show the like and other buttons under the posts .

Answer (score 1):

please try this according to wp documentation

```
// Declare global $more (before the loop).
global $more;
// Set (inside the loop) to display all content, including text below more.
$more = 1;
the_content();
```

Comment: actually the content must display this picture's data (shown in the image after edit) and it shows these on the single page but not the home

Comment: so this won't be counted as the_content will it? how about you post the last few lines off you single page

Comment: i don't know but when i remove the content , this div removes from all page's posts else this just shows up under single pages posts and in the home page , returns nothing even an empty div

Answer (score 1):

`the_content` does not work outside of "The Loop"

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/44153/54343

edit: something akin to this is "the Loop"

```
<?php 
if (have_posts()) { 
  while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    the_content();
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: how can i add this on the loop in this  case ? (sorry i am an amature in the wordpress)

Comment: The loop iterates posts and I am not sure that is what you want on your homepage is it?

Comment: See my edit with the bare minimum needed for the loop

Comment: jesus when i replaced the code with my code , that was something like infinite loop and nothing happend . i must say the content of the posts actually are well . but this the_content shows the share buttons under the posts in the single (when i remove it , just it wont show the icons) in the home it shows nothing

Comment: That's what the_content does. You may need something else if that isn't what you expected.